# Открытие файла на питоне

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы, input

как мне открыть файл через форму with as, чтобы дальше использовать одну из переменных?

через форму with as у меня получается открыть файл, но не получается сделать так, чтобы переменные  `name, tasks, penalty = reader.readline().strip().split(' ')`
работали, вылетает такая ошибка:
`ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.`

Код:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open('input.txt', 'r') as reader:
        _length = int((reader.readline()))

    participants = list()

    for i in range(_length):
        name, tasks, penalty = reader.readline().strip().split(' ')
        participants.append(Participant(name, int(tasks), int(penalty)))


    quicksort(participants)

    print(*participants, sep='\n')
```

Comment: пишите логику внутри `with`. Поскольку ваш `for` идет после закрытия файла на чтение, вы не можете обратиться к `reader`

Comment: спасибо! чего-то сам не додумался до этого....

Comment: А зачем самому до чего-то додумываться. Особенно до того, что явно написано в любой книге по Python или в любой статье в интернет с описанием ввода вывода.  Может все-таки обучение - это когда "сначала читаем, потом делаем", а не когда что-то бездумно копипастим, потом бежим на форум спрашивать, почему у нас ОНО не работает? При том, что ответ на самом деле явно нам дан:"ValueError: I/O operation on closed file".

Comment: суть в том, что смотрел документацию, а не тупо побежал сюда, просто не дошло с первого раза(даже с 3-4).